# Pandas: creating new dataframe based on the names and data of columns in existing dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dataset, data-science

Basically for every **non-nan** row, I want the second part of the column name (after the comma) of that row and store it in new_df - the new dataframe (having the same index as the non-nan value in the existing dataframe) under column named after the first part (before the comma) of its column in the existing dataframe(df).

Sorry about my use of words if it gets clumsy.

- the existing dataframe: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ps97u.png

My code

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame()

for i in range(0, len(df)):
    for j in cols[:3]:
        if df.loc[i, j] != "nan":
            col = j
            x = col.split(',')[1]
            y = col.split(',')[0].split(',')[0]
            new_df[y][i] = x
        else:
            pass
```

In the code above, I was testing with just the politics section and it did not work and I am not sure how I can do that for the whole dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Politics, Very Interested': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 1],
                    'Politics, Not Interested': [np.nan, 1, 1, np.nan]})

col_labels = ['']*len(df.columns)
for c, col in enumerate(df.columns):
    col_name, val = col.split(',')
    df.loc[df[col].notna(), col] = val
    col_labels[c] = col_name

df.columns = col_labels

print(df)
```

which gives you for the subset of the dataframe that I created

```
           Politics         Politics
0               NaN              NaN
1               NaN   Not Interested
2               NaN   Not Interested
3   Very Interested              NaN
```

EDIT:
If now you want to merge columns with the same name and drop NaN then you have to first replace `NaN` with an empty string, then use `groupby` to group columns with the same name and finally use `apply` in combination with `np.max`:

```
df.fillna('', inplace=True)
df = df.groupby(df.columns, axis=1).apply(np.max, axis=1)
```

which for my example gives you

```
           Politics
0                  
1    Not Interested
2    Not Interested
3   Very Interested
```

You can then replace the empty strings with `NaN` if needed.

Comment: Is there a way to merge the columns with the same names so there won't be Nan values

Comment: Yes there is, you have to use `groupby` in combination with `apply`. I edited the answer have a look.

Comment: Thank you. I really appreciate it